# OpenMP thread initialization and de-initialization before doing work

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am using an API that needs to be started and stopped for every thread in which it is used. So if I want to do something with the API in a specific thread I have to call `api_start()` (and `api_stop()` afterwards).

Now I have a very trivial problem I can solve in parallel which I want to try with `OpenMP`. Consider the problem is looking like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS), default(none)
for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    api_process(i);
}
```

This will not work because the worker threads of OpenMP did not call `api_start()` or `api_stop()` so a working solution would be:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS), default(none)
for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    api_start();
    api_process(i);
    api_stop();
}
```

But this solution will bring up overhead because now a thread calls `api_start()` and `api_stop()` multiple times (if `NUM_THREADS < count`).

So my question is: Is there a way in OpenMP to define a function to call for every created thread **once** on startup and **once** on deletion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You can call the functions manually at the beginning/end of the first/last iteration, respectively, or use something as `std::call_once`. However, this would add some overhead into each iteration (branching).</s>

**EDIT**: Actually, this wouldn't work since only a single thread would call those functions. You would need to define some *thread-local* flags and check them in iterations. Same downside.

A much better alternative would be simply to split `parallel` and `for` OpenMP code blocks:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  api_start();

  #pragma omp for
  for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    api_process(i);
  }

  api_stop();
}
```